# I want to store words in an array and then call one of the words

Tags: xcode, swift

Why is it that when I store words in an `array` like this I can't call just on one of the words that I stored. I'll give you an example of what I mean. This is an example of a game that I am working on. I'm doing this in Playground in Xcode using Swift.

```
     var miamiHeat = ["james", "wade", "mario", "allen", "bosh"]
     var questionOne = "Can you name one player from the miami heat?"
     var answerToQuestionOne = ["james", "wade", "mario", "allen", "bosh"]        

     func testIfCorrect(answerToQuestionOne: String) -> String {
     if miamiHeat == answerToQuestionOne {
     println("The answer is correct")

     } else {
     println("The answer is incorrect")
     }      
     return answerToQuestionOne

     }
     println(testIfCorrect("James"))
```

The only way that it will print "The answer is correct" is if I type in all the players name into the last `println` code. When I type in one of the players name into the `println` code it returns "The answer is incorrect." I only need to enter one of the names to get the answer correct.....so how would I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a string with an array, not checking whether the string equals any of the strings within the array.

You need to loop through all the elements in the array, and check equality for each one.

Also, here `println(testIfCorrect("James"))`, you have an uppercase "J", whereas in the array of names it is lowercase (the comparison is case sensitive).

I have amended your code:

```
var miamiHeat = ["james", "wade", "mario", "allen", "bosh"]
    var questionOne = "Can you name one player from the miami heat?"
    var answersToQuestionOne = ["james", "wade", "mario", "allen", "bosh"]

func testIfCorrect(answerToQuestionOne: String) -> String {
    var correctAnswer: Bool = false
    for answer in miamiHeat {
        if answer == answerToQuestionOne {
            correctAnswer = true
        }
    }
    if correctAnswer {
        println("The answer is correct")

    } else {
        println("The answer is incorrect")
    }
    return answerToQuestionOne

}
println(testIfCorrect("james"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because you are comparing the entire structure miamiheat with the answerToQuestionOne. To fix this you could add a switch statement to check each of the possible values of miamiheat. This website has few examples:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html